# MFC - Strange access violation while sending WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, access-violation, sendmessage

I'm currently revising the code on an old MFC application, which I updated to be compiled with Visual Studio 2017. This application contains several MDI frames.

However there is a strange access violation happening randomly when I close these frames, which I cannot figure out, in the main form following function:

```cpp
BOOL PSS_App::OnIdle(LONG count)
{
    if (!count)
        if (m_pMainWnd)
        {
            // look for any top-level windows owned by this class. NOTE handlers are used to
            // avoid generation of too many temporary CWnds
            for (HWND hWnd = ::GetWindow(m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd, GW_HWNDFIRST); hWnd; hWnd = ::GetNextWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT))
                if (::GetParent(hWnd) == m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd)
                {
                    // if owned window is active, move the activation to the application window
                    if (GetActiveWindow() == hWnd && !::GetCapture())
                        m_pMainWnd->SetActiveWindow();

                    // update the buttons for the top-level window
                    ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI, WPARAM(TRUE), 0L);
                }
        }

    return CWinApp::OnIdle(count);
}
```

The issue happens when the `::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI, WPARAM(TRUE), 0L);` function is called. I tried to get the hWnd class name using the following code:

```cpp
char lpClassName[256];
::GetClassName(hWnd, lpClassName, 256);
```

I get `tooltips_class32` as result, but I don't know which class it refers to. If I try to modify the code in the following manner:

```cpp
// update the buttons for the top-level window
if (std::strcmp(lpClassName, "tooltips_class32") != 0)
    ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI, WPARAM(TRUE), 0L);
```

The issue no longer happen in this function, and I can close my child MDI frames without problems, however another access violation happens randomly when the main form looses the focus (e.g when I click outside the app).

Can someone explain me what is happening here, or at least provide me info about what may happen? What the `tooltips_class32` is exactly, and which kind of class may inherits it in MFC? Or is an ActiveX related control?

**NOTE** I don't know if that may have a link, but the main application inherits from CWinApp, which inherits from CWinThread. The application isn't using the multi-threading, except for the splash screen. However the issue remains the same even if I completely deactivate the splash screen code.

**NOTE** also that the application is a huge application containing around 30 attached DLLs. I cannot run it in Debug for now, because another strange access violation happens in one of the modules when it is loaded, which happen in Debug but never in Release. So the application is currently running in release.

Comment: Compile your application in Release, but turn on the debugging in the project settings for the Release mode.  Then run the app under the debugger.  Nothing prevents having the debugging turned on for a release app.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, indeed it's what I did. However this not allowed me to fix the issue, the debugger lost me in the MFC code.

Comment: Don't know how big your application is, but maybe you could check the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handlers, seems there is some bad code there. For example, checking some data structure or object that no longer exists (after closing an MDI child or view). Esp check global or stored variables like handles. If it's not very much work, you could even try commenting out those handlers one by one and checking the results. Otherwise, do some code inspections at least.

Comment: I'd start fixing the access violations in debug mode first and then worry about bugs in release mode.

Comment: The window class *"tooltip_class32"* is the name of that standard [tooltip control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tooltip-controls). An MFC class does not inherit from standard controls; it encapsulates it. Yanking out the owning window from underneath a tooltip, without destroying the tooltip is surely going to cause havoc in MFC's tooltip wrapper code.

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou If you want to have an idea, the whole project is open source and may be accessed on my GitHub page: https://github.com/Jeanmilost/Visual-Mercutio. This is an application I worked on more than 10 years ago, and the company which owned this app decided to share the source code. Otherwise I will try your suggestion as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I already tried to resolve that since a long time ago, without success, unfortunately. AFAIK may be a bug from Visual Studio itself (seen several posts about that at the time).

Comment: Were you able to figure the AV error out? In our own application we face Access violations in the afx internal message loop when messages, sent using sendmessage and postmessage are processed.

Comment: @ShameelMohamed unfortunately not, I have no new info about this issue. As it wasn't happening in a crucial part of my code, I either disabled the functionality, or I let it as is, I don't remember. Hope you'll find a solution.

Comment: @Jean-MilostReymond I have figured out the issue Jean. Will share it here, if you feel that could be the same with your code as well, maybe we can convert it into an answer.

Comment: I have a simple interface that doesn't depend on anything and the method overridden from this interface was mapped to a msg. And the AV occurred when processing this msg in the afx message pump. The MFC system expects the methods mapped to it's messages to be of the signature CWnd::X_name(WPARAM and the CWnd part is where my overridden method digresses. I tried simply inheriting CDialog(it is implicitly derived from CWnd) into the interface and all the AVs were resolved. If possible you can try the same.

Comment: Though this is not the right approach as the interface is not simple anymore, in my case all the implementations of the interface are CDialogs so I just went with propagating the CDialog.